# How can I modify a binding so that it adds " pts" if the bound value is not ""?

Tags: c#

I am using a ViewModel to set the number of points on my display. Is there a way that I could modify this so that when the value of points is "0" or another not empty that it adds " pts"  but when it's "" it still displays ""

```
    string _points;
    public string Points
    {
        get => _points;
        set => SetProperty(ref _points, value);
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you are using WPF I would suggest to keep the numeric information about the number of points in an integer property. Bind that integer property to your Label / TextBox/ etc. with an IValueConverter. Use the IValueConverter to convert from integer to string. Put your display logic into the Convert method of the IValueConverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on replys from OP on my other answer.

```
public static Points _points { get; set; }

class Points
{
    private int? i; 

    public static implicit operator Points(int value)
    {
        return new Points { i.Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Points value)
    {
         if(Value.i.HasValue)
             return value.i.Value.ToString();
          return "";
    }

     public static implicit operator int(Points value)
    {   
        return value.I.HasValue ?value.i.value : 0;
    }
}
```

and using the new Points struct:

```
_points += 2;         // 2
string s = points;    // "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a check if the `_string` is `"0"` before returning it to the view, in your `Points` property:

```
get => _points.Equals("0") ? "0 pts" : _points;
```

And to tidy it up, put it into a method:

```
public string ReturnPoints() =>  _points.Equals("0") ? "0 pts" : _points;
```

And then in your `Points` property:

```
string _points;
public string Points
{
    get => ReturnPoints();
    set => SetProperty(ref _points, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That looks great. One quick question.  Later I want to check the int value of the string vm.Points.  How can I convert vm.Points to an int?

Comment: Something like var points = int.Parse(Points.Replace("pts", "")); and points will be an integer, then you can do some work on it. I would recommend in your SetProperty that you append the _points with "pts" so that when you use it - Points = "10", and then Console.WriteLine(Points); outputs 10 pts, this will remove the problem of setting "0" and getting "0" rather than "0 pts"

Comment: So would that last statement return a 0 if vm.Points was ""?  What I need to do is to add a number to vm.Points.  Like vm.Points = vm.Points + pts;  where pts is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you can try this.

use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method to check string whether empty, if no append pts to the end string, otherwise return `""`.

```
string _points;
public string Points
{  
    get => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_points) ? $"{_points} pts" : string.Empty;
    set => SetProperty(ref _points, value);
}
```